# C: fork() - Child and Parent not acting as expected

Tags: c, process, fork

My code below `fork()`s a process creating its Child, they both call the same function, which will basically have a loop. Inside, they sleep for a random amount of seconds between 0 and 5, then they print a silly message showing which pass has finished. Finally they print an "exiting" message and leave.

The problem is that, every time the Child prints the "exiting" message, the Parent (apparently) prints the same, even though the parent is still 1 or 2 passes before finishing. When the Parent finishes, it will print again the "exiting" message. If the Parent finishes before the Child, it will print the "exiting" message when it finishes, and again when the Child finishes.

Now, if I exit or return inside the Child if clause, after my function, then the Parent "exiting" message is not printed. This is leading me to believe the Child is printing the "exiting" message on behalf of the Parent. So, what is causing the Parent "exiting" message to be printed twice?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

const int PASS = 5;
const int RANDLIMIT = 5;
int i = 0;

void doSomeWork(char *who);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("Just started, I am: %d\n", (int) getpid());
  pid_t pid = fork();
  printf("fork returned: %d\n", (int) pid);
  srand((int) pid);

  if (pid < 0) {
    perror("fork failed");
  } else if (pid == 0) {
    doSomeWork("Child");
    // if I exit(0) or return(0) here, it behaves accordingly.
  }
  doSomeWork("Parent");
  return(0);
}

void doSomeWork(char *who)
{
  int control = 0;
  for(; i < PASS; i++){
    sleep(rand() % RANDLIMIT);
    printf("%s: Done pass #%d\n", who, i);
  }
  printf("%s: exiting...\n", who);
}
```

Child finishing first:

```
[root@centos ~]# ./fork3
Just started, I am: 18232
fork returned: 18233
fork returned: 0
Child: Done pass #0
Parent: Done pass #0
Child: Done pass #1
Child: Done pass #2
Child: Done pass #3
Parent: Done pass #1
Parent: Done pass #2
Child: Done pass #4
Child: exiting...
Parent: exiting...
Parent: Done pass #3
Parent: Done pass #4
Parent: exiting...
```

Parent finishing first:

```
[root@centos ~]# ./fork3
Just started, I am: 19507
fork returned: 19508
Parent: Done pass #0
Parent: Done pass #1
fork returned: 0
Child: Done pass #0
Parent: Done pass #2
Parent: Done pass #3
Child: Done pass #1
Child: Done pass #2
Child: Done pass #3
Parent: Done pass #4
Parent: exiting...
[root@centos ~]# Child: Done pass #4
Child: exiting...
Parent: exiting...
```

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Especially count how many times the `doSomework` is called in the *child* process. An `else` clause could be useful to solve your problem.

Comment: On a related note, you should make it a habit for the parent to [`wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) for its children.

Comment: I saw somewhere that the else was not used, but I think they had an exit(0) there and I forgot to put it. I'm not using wait on purpose, as I want to see the Child process becoming orphan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `doSomeWork("Parent")` in *both* the parent and the child. That's why `exit` makes it work - then the child terminates right before calling `doSomeWork("Parent")`.

A solution would be:

```
if (pid < 0) {
    perror("fork failed");
} else if (pid == 0) {
    doSomeWork("Child");
} else {
    doSomeWork("Parent");
}
```

And of course remember that both process run simultaneously, so the order of execution is unpredictable (the usual multitasking problems apply).

Comment: I think you are right, I saw somewhere that else was not used, but I think they had an exit(0) there and I forgot. Thanks.